# SharedPreferences keep getting default value

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I keep Getting the Default value either my UI will display null or if I use integers it displays that default value as well here it is in the string form plz help

```
//putting the information in shared preferences
TextView pScore1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pScore1f);


SharedPreferences peepsScores2= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(GamePlayFirst.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 =peepsScores2.edit();
String userScore11 = pScore1.getText().toString();
  editor2.putString("userScore11",userScore11);
  editor2.commit();

  //getting it and editing it

  SharedPreferences peepsScores2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int u;
    int one =1;
    int newUsrScore1=1;
    String userScore11 = peepsScores2.getString("userScore11",null);
    u=Integer.parseInt(userScore11);
        newUsrScore1 = u+one;
        String newUserScore1  = Integer.toString(newUsrScore1);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = peepsScores2.edit();
    editor.putString(newUserScore1, NewUserScore1);
      editor.commit();

    //getting it and displaying it on the UI

    SharedPreferences peepsScores2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userScore11 = peepsScores2.getString("NewuserScore1",null);


  pScore1.setText(" "+userScore11);
```

Comment: try looking at the xml and see whether commit is successful.

Comment: you are not calling commit after editing it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added some comment to you code please check:

```
//putting the information in shared preferences
TextView pScore1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pScore1f);


SharedPreferences peepsScores2= 

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(GamePlayFirst.this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 =peepsScores2.edit();
String userScore11 = pScore1.getText().toString();
  editor2.putString("userScore11",userScore11);
  editor2.commit();

  //getting it and editing it

  SharedPreferences peepsScores2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int u;
    int one =1;
    int newUsrScore1=1;
    String userScore11 = peepsScores2.getString("userScore11",null);
    u=Integer.parseInt(userScore11);
        newUsrScore1 = u+one;
        String newUserScore1  = Integer.toString(newUsrScore1);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = peepsScores2.edit();

     //@Praful: here newUserScore1 seems to be integer value and you are storing 
    //null here. I think it it should be 
    //`editor.putString("NewuserScore1", newUsrScore1);`
    editor.putString(newUserScore1, null);

     //@Praful: call commit here
    editor.commit;

    //getting it and displaying it on the UI

    SharedPreferences peepsScores2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String userScore11 = peepsScores2.getString("NewuserScore1",null);


  pScore1.setText(" "+userScore11);
```

Comment: this answer solved my similar problem too, I forget to put in editor.commit(); after adding that it worked!! :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

This line

`editor.putString(newUserScore1, null);`

should be

```
editor.putString("NewuserScore1",newUserScore1);
```

and also don't forget to commit your changes using `editor.commit();`

Comment: commit isthere i missed it on the cop paste and when i changed the null to newUserScore1 it still says null in my UI

Comment: capitol N haha im the worst typer ever ty

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you working with SharedPreference never forget to call `commit()` to save your changes.

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = peepsScores2.edit();
    editor.putString("NewuserScore1", newUserScore1);
    editor.commit();
```